# Should I worry about my iPhone 4's loose back panel? 

Tags: iphone, hardware

A few weeks ago I got my iPhone 4 replaced by Apple because of a fault. The replacement now seems to have a loose back panel. If I try to slide it sideways it will move a bit. None of the other people I know with an iPhone 4 have encountered this and I'm not sure if I should be bothered taking it back to the store or just keeping it.

Should the loose panel be cause for concern, or is it nothing to worry about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering how much an iPhone costs, take it back. If not for the fact that a loose panel will eventually expose the interior of the phone, thus requiring you to take it back anyway, then for the simple fact that we, as a customer base, expect better of Apple products.

Comment: +1. Pretty much anything that's "loose" is only headed one direction: looser.